# How to output hostname in "service Description" for nagios core?

Tags: nagios

I have currently the following two service defined as below:

```
define service {
        use                             my-webapp-service
        hostgroup_name                  all
        service_description             System check - PING
        check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }
define service {
        use                             my-webapp-service
        hostgroup_name                  all
        service_description             System check - Swap Usage
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_swap
        check_interval                  1
        }
```

What I want is output string to be:
**System check - PING - "Actual hostname where this alarm got fired off"**

**System check - Swap Usage - "Actual hostname where this alarm got fired off"**

I think this could be possible but I just don't know how to make it possible.
Would sincerely appreciate your guidance on that.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Output are handled by scripts. Default behavior is that script don´t return hostname, because it is not necessary.
If you wanna add hostname in output, you must edit already exist scripts or create new one.
Here is basic info how create script for Nagios - http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/06/how-to-create-nagios-plugin-using-bash-script.html
For your needs you must add `$HOSTNAME` to *echo*. For instance:

```
echo "$HOSTNAME - WARNING- $output"
```

Comment: Yep, this is possible, because some script work only with specific OS.  You must modify these script for your OS (and version).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script that is executing to be aware of the hostname, you'll need to pass the hostname as an argument to the Nagios command. That also means that the script will need to accept the hostname as an argument. Take for example:

```
define service {
        use                             my-webapp-service
        hostgroup_name                  all
        service_description             System check - PING
        check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }
```

`check_ping` probably looks something like:

```
define command {
       command_name                             check_ping
       command_line                             $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p 5
}
```

The problem here is that the executable at `$USER1$/check_ping` doesn't know that you want to pass the host's name as an argument. So you'll need to make a wrapper script. I'm not going to write the script for you, but to give you a hint, the command definition would look something like:

```
define command {
       command_name                             check_ping_print_hostname
       command_line                             $USER1$/my_check_ping_wrapper.sh --hostname $HOSTNAME$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p 5
}
```

And then the script at `$USER1$/my_check_ping_wrapper.sh` is obviously going to need grab that `--hostname` argument, and then pass the other arguments directly to check_ping, wait for the output, and then amend the output with the information given in the `--hostname` arg.

Hope this helps!